# Java -version will not update after SDK installation

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having an issue launching Eclipse saying incorrect JVM version(1.5, needs 1.7+), I installed both Java 7 and 8 from the website but when checking the version in cmd, i am still seeing 1.5

```
java version "1.5.0_30"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_30-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_30-b03, mixed mode)
```

It was my understanding that when I install a newer jdk, this version would update.  How can I manually update this?

My Java_Home variable is pointing to the newer jdk.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_79
```

Comment: Chances are it's your PATH environment variable that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

check your PATH environment variable

Answer (score 2):

Start eclipse with the `-vm` argument, followed by the address of the jvm you want to use.

This way, you'll be sure of the version you're using.

Example:

```
eclipse.exe -vm C:\_jde\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add your JAVA_HOME variable to path as well.
appending the JAVA_HOME like this should set java 7 to default in your system .

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

or you can check this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_environment_setup.htm) to see how to set java.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely that your system variable is still having this. Please recheck your system variable.

Also, you have an option of setting your default JRE:

```
Open Eclipse.
Navigate to Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs
Set your default JRE
```

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue whenever i switch between various Java versions. The solution is below:

Go to `c:\Windows\system32`
Delete `java.exe, javaw.exe, javaws.exe` files

Open the command prompt and check the java -version.

Hope this is helpful!